# how to make checkbox stay checked when program closes?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

In my program I have around 20 check boxes however when I check them and close the program then go back on the check boxes they are always unchecked how can I make the check box remember to stay checked.

Answer (score 2):

In your onPause function, write the states to a file or to a SharedPreference.  In your onResume, read that file/Preference in and set the checkboxes.  You may want to look at PreferenceActivity to do this for you.

Comment: how would i write that in android sdk and how can i use it for all 20 checkboxes

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to do this.

So first, when your application goes to `onPause`, you'll want to store the state of each checkbox in `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.myapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.putBoolean("checkbox1", checkbox1.isChecked()).commit();
// do this for all 20
```

Then you can check the checkboxes `onResume` and `onCreate`:

```
checkbox1.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("checkbox1", false));
```

Comment: how can i write that for 20 checkboxes

Answer (score 2):

You should look into using [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) .

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Writing to Shared Preferences :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

Reading from Shared Preferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

Also here is a very simple [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) on implementing them.

Requested Example Code :

Main Activity Class :

```
package com.zeus.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

CheckBox chkBox1, chkBox2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    chkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    chkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

    SharedPreferences getPrefs = 
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    boolean value = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox_preference", true);
    chkBox1.setSelected(value); // Setting the value reflected from the preference
    chkBox2.setSelected(!value); // Setting the value opposite of the preference(Just an example)
}
}
```

Preference Activity Class :

```
package com.zeus.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity{

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
   }
}
```

Settings XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <CheckBoxPreference
               android:key="checkbox_preference"
               android:defaultValue="false"
              android:title="CheckBox1"
        />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Although this method is easy, it's deprecated and is recommended to use Preference Fragments instead**

Comment: i dont really understand the tutorial vary much can you just show me how to implement it on two check boxes so then i can have a clue on how i can use it for the other 20

Comment: @user3604788  : Edited original post to include the example code. Enjoy :)

Comment: its doesnt work plus is there an easy way for me to do this 20 times

Answer (score 1):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). The simplest way to store small values forever.

Since you have multiple check boxes use [SharedPreferences.Editor putStringSet (String key, Set<String> values)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)

You can use [SimpleSharedPreferences](https://github.com/VenomVendor/SimpleSharedPreferences) in which `putStringSet` is backported to API-1.

**Usage:** No Edit, No Commit.

```
SimpleSharedPreferences mPreferences = new SimpleSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()); //Init.

mPreferences.putStringSet("STRING_SET_KEY", mStringSet); //Single Line 

mPreferences.getStringSet("STRING_SET_KEY", null); // Get String set.

mPreferences.putBoolean("INTEGER_BOOL", true); //Just an example.
```

Note : I am the author of SimpleSharePreferences.